# Improve scipy.integrate.quad_vec performance for fitting integral equation, workers keyword non-functional

Tags: python, performance, scipy, curve-fitting

I am using `quad_vec` in a function that contains an integral not solvable with analytic methods. I need to fit this equation to data points.

However, even the evaluation with fixed values takes multiple seconds, the total fit time grows to 7 min.

Is there a way to accelerate the computation? I know `quad_vec` has the `workers` keyword, but when I try to use that, the computation does not finish at all.
I am currently working in a Jupyter notebook if that has any significance.

This is the function definition, I already tried to use numba here with little success.

```py
from scipy.special import j0, j1
from scipy.integrate import quad_vec
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

h = 0.00005
G = 1000
E = 3*G
R= 0.0002
upsilon = 0.06
gamma = 0.072

@nb.jit(nb.float64(nb.float64, nb.float64, nb.float64, nb.float64, nb.float64),cache=True)
def QSzz_1(s,h,z, upsilon, E):
    # exponential form of the QSzz^-1 function to prevent float overflow,
    # also assumes nu==0.5
    numerator = (1+2*s**2*h**2)*np.exp(-2*s*z) + 0.5*(1+np.exp(-4*s*z))
    denominator = 0.5*(1-np.exp(-4*s*z)) - 2*s*h*np.exp(-2*s*z)
    return (3/(2*s*E)) / (numerator/denominator + (3*upsilon/(2*E))*s)

def integrand(s, r, R, upsilon, E, h):
    return s*(R*j0(s*R) - 2*j1(s*R)/s) * QSzz_1(s,h,h, upsilon, E) * j0(s*r)

def style_exact(r, gamma, R, upsilon, E, h):               
    int_out = quad_vec(integrand, 0, np.inf, args=(r,R,upsilon,E,h))
    return gamma * int_out[0]

# calculate fixed ~10s
x_ax = np.linspace(0, 0.0004,101, endpoint=True, dtype=np.float64)
zeta = style_exact(x_ax, gamma, 0.0002, upsilon, E, h)

# fit to dataset (wetting ridge) ~7 min
popt_hemi, pcov_hemi = curve_fit(lambda x, upsilon, E, h: style_exact(x, gamma, R, upsilon, E, h) ,points_x, points_y, p0=(upsilon, E, h), bounds=([0,0,0],[np.inf,np.inf,np.inf]))
```

Edit:
here are some exemplar values:

```py
points_x =[0.00040030286, 0.00040155788, 0.00040281289, 0.00040406791000000003, 0.00040532292, 0.00040657794, 0.00040783296, 0.00040908797, 0.00041034299, 0.00041159801, 0.00041285302, 0.00041410804, 0.00041536305, 0.00041661807, 0.00041787309, 0.0004191281, 0.00042038312, 0.00042163814, 0.00042289315000000003, 0.00042414817000000003, 0.00042540318, 0.0004266582, 0.00042791322, 0.00042916823, 0.00043042325, 0.00043167827, 0.00043293328, 0.0004341883, 0.00043544332, 0.00043669833, 0.00043795335, 0.00043920836, 0.00044046338, 0.0004417184, 0.00044297341000000003, 0.00044422843000000003, 0.00044548345, 0.00044673846, 0.00044799348, 0.00044924849, 0.00045050351, 0.00045175852999999996, 0.00045301354000000006, 0.00045426856, 0.00045552357999999995, 0.00045677859000000005, 0.00045803361, 0.00045928863000000006, 0.00046054364000000004, 0.00046179866, 0.00046305367, 0.00046430869000000004, 0.00046556371, 0.00046681871999999997, 0.00046807374000000003, 0.00046932876, 0.00047058376999999996, 0.00047183879, 0.0004730938, 0.00047434881999999995, 0.00047560384, 0.00047685885, 0.00047811387000000006, 0.00047936889, 0.0004806239, 0.00048187892000000005, 0.00048313393000000004, 0.00048438895, 0.00048564397000000004, 0.00048689898000000003, 0.000488154, 0.00048940902, 0.00049066403, 0.00049191905, 0.00049317407, 0.00049442908, 0.0004956841, 0.0004969391100000001, 0.00049819413, 0.0004994491500000001, 0.00050070416, 0.00050195918, 0.0005032142, 0.00050446921, 0.00050572423, 0.00050697924, 0.00050823426, 0.00050948928, 0.00051074429, 0.00051199931, 0.00051325433, 0.00051450934, 0.00051576436, 0.00051701937, 0.0005182743900000001, 0.00051952941, 0.00052078442, 0.00052203944, 0.00052329446, 0.00052454947, 0.00052580449, 0.00052705951, 0.00052831452, 0.00052956954, 0.00053082455, 0.00053207957, 0.00053333459, 0.0005345896, 0.00053584462, 0.00053709964, 0.00053835465, 0.00053960967, 0.00054086468, 0.0005421197, 0.0005433747200000001, 0.00054462973, 0.00054588475, 0.00054713977, 0.00054839478, 0.0005496498, 0.00055090482, 0.00055215983, 0.00055341485, 0.00055466986, 0.00055592488, 0.0005571799, 0.00055843491, 0.00055968993, 0.00056094495, 0.0005621999600000001, 0.00056345498, 0.00056470999, 0.00056596501, 0.00056722003, 0.00056847504, 0.00056973006, 0.00057098508, 0.00057224009, 0.00057349511, 0.00057475012, 0.00057600514, 0.00057726016, 0.00057851517, 0.00057977019, 0.00058102521, 0.00058228022, 0.0005835352400000001, 0.00058479026, 0.00058604527, 0.00058730029, 0.0005885553, 0.00058981032, 0.00059106534, 0.00059232035, 0.00059357537, 0.00059483039, 0.0005960854, 0.00059734042, 0.00059859543, 0.00059985045, 0.00060110547, 0.0006023604800000001, 0.0006036155, 0.00060487052, 0.00060612553, 0.00060738055, 0.00060863556, 0.00060989058, 0.0006111456, 0.00061240061, 0.00061365563, 0.00061491065, 0.00061616566, 0.00061742068, 0.0006186757, 0.00061993071, 0.00062118573, 0.00062244074, 0.00062369576, 0.00062495078, 0.00062620579, 0.0006274608100000001, 0.00062871583, 0.00062997084, 0.00063122586, 0.00063248087, 0.00063373589, 0.00063499091, 0.00063624592, 0.00063750094, 0.00063875596, 0.00064001097, 0.00064126599, 0.000642521, 0.00064377602, 0.00064503104, 0.0006462860500000001, 0.00064754107, 0.0006487960900000001, 0.0006500511, 0.00065130612, 0.00065256114, 0.00065381615, 0.00065507117, 0.00065632618, 0.0006575812, 0.00065883622, 0.00066009123, 0.00066134625, 0.00066260127, 0.00066385628, 0.0006651113, 0.00066636631, 0.0006676213300000001, 0.00066887635, 0.00067013136, 0.00067138638, 0.0006726414, 0.00067389641, 0.00067515143, 0.00067640645, 0.00067766146, 0.00067891648, 0.00068017149, 0.00068142651, 0.00068268153, 0.00068393654, 0.00068519156, 0.00068644658, 0.00068770159, 0.00068895661, 0.00069021162, 0.00069146664, 0.0006927216600000001, 0.00069397667, 0.00069523169, 0.00069648671, 0.00069774172, 0.00069899674, 0.00070025175, 0.00070150677, 0.00070276179, 0.0007040168, 0.00070527182, 0.00070652684, 0.00070778185, 0.00070903687, 0.00071029189, 0.0007115469000000001, 0.00071280192, 0.00071405693, 0.00071531195, 0.00071656697, 0.00071782198, 0.000719077, 0.00072033202, 0.00072158703, 0.00072284205, 0.00072409706, 0.00072535208, 0.0007266071, 0.00072786211, 0.00072911713, 0.00073037215, 0.00073162716, 0.0007328821800000001, 0.00073413719, 0.00073539221, 0.00073664723, 0.00073790224, 0.00073915726, 0.00074041228, 0.00074166729, 0.00074292231, 0.00074417733, 0.00074543234, 0.00074668736, 0.00074794237, 0.00074919739, 0.00075045241, 0.0007517074200000001, 0.00075296244, 0.00075421746, 0.00075547247, 0.00075672749, 0.0007579825, 0.00075923752, 0.00076049254, 0.00076174755, 0.00076300257, 0.00076425759, 0.0007655126, 0.00076676762, 0.00076802264, 0.00076927765, 0.00077053267, 0.00077178768, 0.0007730427, 0.00077429772, 0.00077555273, 0.0007768077500000001, 0.00077806277, 0.00077931778, 0.0007805728, 0.00078182781, 0.00078308283, 0.00078433785, 0.00078559286, 0.00078684788, 0.0007881029, 0.00078935791, 0.00079061293, 0.00079186794, 0.00079312296, 0.00079437798, 0.0007956329900000001, 0.00079688801, 0.0007981430300000001, 0.00079939804, 0.00080065306, 0.00080190808, 0.00080316309, 0.00080441811, 0.00080567312, 0.00080692814, 0.00080818316, 0.00080943817, 0.00081069319, 0.00081194821, 0.00081320322, 0.00081445824, 0.00081571325, 0.0008169682700000001, 0.00081822329, 0.0008194783, 0.00082073332, 0.00082198834, 0.00082324335, 0.00082449837, 0.00082575338, 0.0008270084, 0.00082826342, 0.00082951843, 0.00083077345, 0.00083202847, 0.00083328348, 0.0008345385, 0.00083579352, 0.00083704853, 0.00083830355, 0.00083955856, 0.00084081358, 0.0008420686000000001, 0.00084332361, 0.00084457863, 0.00084583365, 0.00084708866, 0.00084834368, 0.00084959869, 0.00085085371, 0.00085210873, 0.00085336374, 0.00085461876, 0.00085587378, 0.00085712879, 0.00085838381, 0.00085963882, 0.0008608938400000001, 0.00086214886, 0.00086340387, 0.00086465889, 0.00086591391, 0.00086716892, 0.00086842394, 0.00086967896, 0.00087093397, 0.00087218899, 0.000873444, 0.00087469902, 0.00087595404, 0.00087720905, 0.00087846407, 0.00087971909, 0.0008809741, 0.0008822291200000001, 0.00088348413, 0.00088473915, 0.00088599417, 0.00088724918, 0.0008885042, 0.00088975922, 0.00089101423, 0.00089226925, 0.00089352427, 0.00089477928, 0.0008960343, 0.00089728931, 0.00089854433, 0.00089979935, 0.0009010543600000001, 0.00090230938, 0.0009035644, 0.00090481941, 0.00090607443, 0.00090732944, 0.00090858446, 0.00090983948, 0.00091109449, 0.00091234951, 0.00091360453, 0.00091485954, 0.00091611456, 0.00091736957, 0.00091862459, 0.00091987961, 0.00092113462, 0.00092238964, 0.00092364466, 0.00092489967, 0.0009261546900000001, 0.00092740971, 0.00092866472, 0.00092991974, 0.00093117475, 0.00093242977, 0.00093368479, 0.0009349398, 0.00093619482, 0.00093744984, 0.00093870485, 0.0009399598700000001, 0.00094121488, 0.0009424699, 0.0009437249200000001, 0.00094497993, 0.00094623495, 0.0009474899700000001, 0.0009487449799999999, 0.00095, 0.0009512550100000001, 0.0009525100299999999, 0.00095376505, 0.0009550200600000001, 0.0009562750799999999, 0.0009575301, 0.0009587851100000001, 0.0009600401299999999, 0.00096129515, 0.00096255017, 0.00096380517, 0.0009650601700000001, 0.00096631517, 0.00096757027, 0.0009688252700000001, 0.00097008027, 0.0009713352699999999, 0.0009725902700000001, 0.00097384527, 0.0009751003699999999, 0.0009763553700000001, 0.00097761037, 0.00097886537, 0.00098012037, 0.0009813753699999999, 0.0009826304699999998, 0.0009838854700000002, 0.00098514047, 0.00098639547, 0.00098765047, 0.0009889054699999998, 0.0009901605699999998, 0.0009914155700000002, 0.00099267057, 0.00099392557, 0.00099518057, 0.0009964355699999998, 0.0009976905700000002, 0.0009989456700000001, 0.00100020067, 0.00100145567, 0.00100271067, 0.0010039656699999998, 0.0010052206700000002, 0.0010064757700000001, 0.00100773077, 0.00100898577, 0.0010102407699999999, 0.0010114957699999998, 0.0010127507700000002, 0.00101400587, 0.00101526087, 0.00101651587, 0.0010177708699999999, 0.0010190258700000002, 0.0010202808700000001, 0.00102153597, 0.00102279097, 0.00102404597, 0.0010253009699999998, 0.0010265559700000002, 0.0010278109700000001, 0.00102906607, 0.00103032107, 0.00103157607, 0.0010328310699999998, 0.0010340860700000002, 0.00103534107, 0.00103659617, 0.00103785117, 0.00103910617, 0.0010403611699999998, 0.0010416161700000002, 0.00104287117, 0.00104412627, 0.00104538127, 0.0010466362699999999, 0.0010478912699999998, 0.0010491462700000002, 0.00105040127, 0.00105165627, 0.00105291137, 0.0010541663699999999, 0.0010554213700000002, 0.0010566763700000001, 0.00105793137, 0.00105918637, 0.00106044147, 0.0010616964699999999, 0.0010629514700000002, 0.0010642064700000001, 0.00106546147, 0.00106671647, 0.00106797157, 0.0010692265699999998, 0.0010704815700000002, 0.00107173657, 0.00107299157, 0.00107424657, 0.00107550167, 0.0010767566699999998, 0.0010780116700000002, 0.00107926667, 0.00108052167, 0.00108177667, 0.0010830317699999999, 0.0010842867699999998, 0.0010855417700000002, 0.00108679677, 0.00108805177, 0.00108930677, 0.0010905618699999999, 0.0010918168700000002, 0.0010930718700000001, 0.00109432687, 0.00109558187, 0.00109683687, 0.0010980919699999999, 0.0010993469700000002, 0.0011006019700000001, 0.00110185697, 0.00110311197, 0.0011043669699999999, 0.0011056219699999998, 0.0011068770700000002, 0.00110813207, 0.00110938707, 0.00111064207, 0.0011118970699999999, 0.0011131520700000002, 0.0011144071700000002, 0.00111566217, 0.00111691717, 0.00111817217, 0.0011194271699999998, 0.0011206821700000002, 0.0011219372700000002, 0.00112319227, 0.00112444727, 0.00112570227, 0.0011269572699999998, 0.0011282122700000002, 0.0011294673700000001, 0.00113072237, 0.00113197737, 0.00113323237, 0.0011344873699999998, 0.0011357423700000002, 0.0011369974700000001, 0.00113825247, 0.00113950747, 0.0011407624699999999, 0.0011420174699999998, 0.0011432724700000002, 0.0011445275700000001, 0.00114578257, 0.00114703757, 0.0011482925699999999, 0.0011495475700000002, 0.0011508025700000001, 0.00115205767, 0.00115331267, 0.00115456767, 0.0011558226699999999, 0.0011570776700000002, 0.0011583326700000001, 0.00115958777, 0.00116084277, 0.00116209777, 0.0011633527699999998, 0.0011646077700000002, 0.00116586277, 0.00116711777, 0.00116837287, 0.00116962787, 0.0011708828699999998, 0.0011721378700000002, 0.00117339287, 0.00117464787, 0.00117590297, 0.0011771579699999999, 0.0011784129699999998, 0.0011796679700000002, 0.00118092297, 0.00118217797, 0.00118343307, 0.0011846880699999999, 0.0011859430700000002, 0.0011871980700000001, 0.00118845307, 0.00118970807, 0.00119096317, 0.0011922181699999999, 0.0011934731700000002, 0.0011947281700000001, 0.00119598317, 0.00119723817, 0.00119849327, 0.0011997482699999998, 0.0012010032700000002, 0.00120225827, 0.00120351327, 0.00120476827, 0.00120602337, 0.0012072783699999998, 0.0012085333700000002, 0.00120978837, 0.00121104337, 0.00121229837, 0.0012135534699999999, 0.0012148084699999998, 0.0012160634700000002, 0.00121731847, 0.00121857347, 0.00121982847, 0.0012210834699999998, 0.0012223385700000002, 0.0012235935700000001, 0.00122484857, 0.00122610357, 0.00122735857, 0.0012286135699999998, 0.0012298686700000002, 0.0012311236700000001, 0.00123237867, 0.00123363367, 0.0012348886699999999, 0.0012361436699999998]


points_y = [-2.4929826e-07, -2.3248189e-07, -4.4305314e-07, -1.0689171e-06, -7.0144722e-07, -1.3773717e-06, -9.3672285e-07, -1.6876499e-06, -9.8346007e-07, -1.7992562e-06, -1.0198111e-06, -1.721233e-06, -8.9082583e-07, -1.1925362e-06, -8.3776501e-07, -6.9998957e-07, -7.1134901e-07, -4.5476849e-07, -6.4449894e-07, -3.8765887e-07, -6.3044764e-07, -7.4224008e-07, -7.6114851e-07, -1.0377502e-06, -1.3589471e-06, -1.3342596e-06, -1.3712255e-06, -1.3510569e-06, -1.2278933e-06, -8.2319036e-07, -1.4040568e-06, -6.4183121e-07, -1.1649824e-06, -7.3197454e-07, -1.0537769e-06, -8.3223932e-07, -1.1644648e-06, -1.2177416e-06, -1.4045247e-06, -1.6934001e-06, -1.6157397e-06, -1.8595331e-06, -1.7097882e-06, -1.8031869e-06, -1.5406345e-06, -1.5851084e-06, -1.5695719e-06, -1.4990693e-06, -1.8087735e-06, -1.7151045e-06, -1.8353234e-06, -1.71844e-06, -1.7904118e-06, -1.5297879e-06, -1.6064767e-06, -1.4520618e-06, -1.1090131e-06, -1.2475477e-06, -7.4591269e-07, -1.0619496e-06, -7.5699762e-07, -1.3883064e-06, -1.3300594e-06, -1.9713711e-06, -2.0613271e-06, -2.5116161e-06, -2.4466345e-06, -2.5386926e-06, -2.2368298e-06, -2.2934508e-06, -1.8951084e-06, -1.8117756e-06, -1.6680112e-06, -1.8274169e-06, -1.7569355e-06, -2.1081536e-06, -2.1241154e-06, -2.2742958e-06, -2.4032149e-06, -2.2596226e-06, -2.1889918e-06, -1.9359605e-06, -1.8878718e-06, -1.6144539e-06, -1.6485844e-06, -1.2316506e-06, -1.6932815e-06, -8.1348768e-07, -1.310099e-06, -4.3574574e-07, -1.0726973e-06, -6.6005902e-07, -1.2151841e-06, -9.1100721e-07, -1.4911344e-06, -1.3152027e-06, -1.3695714e-06, -1.3930563e-06, -1.3452594e-06, -1.3228626e-06, -1.3714694e-06, -1.2480971e-06, -1.4622823e-06, -1.5687181e-06, -1.7872703e-06, -1.7135845e-06, -2.0209804e-06, -1.3665688e-06, -1.7074398e-06, -1.1511678e-06, -1.1604734e-06, -1.0173458e-06, -1.0660268e-06, -1.0424449e-06, -1.1101976e-06, -1.0030326e-06, -1.0879421e-06, -8.2978143e-07, -9.3823628e-07, -7.2342249e-07, -9.8929055e-07, -1.0764783e-06, -1.3105722e-06, -1.3954326e-06, -1.5047949e-06, -1.4339143e-06, -1.3061363e-06, -1.3200332e-06, -1.381963e-06, -1.3490984e-06, -1.3526509e-06, -1.463083e-06, -1.2588114e-06, -1.4445926e-06, -1.1240129e-06, -1.3659935e-06, -1.3323392e-06, -1.3695779e-06, -1.7108472e-06, -1.7111548e-06, -2.0250494e-06, -2.1803196e-06, -2.2433208e-06, -2.4435685e-06, -1.9341618e-06, -2.3866277e-06, -1.8497934e-06, -1.8903583e-06, -1.4422203e-06, -1.7661343e-06, -1.5059728e-06, -1.5770287e-06, -1.8108199e-06, -2.0170832e-06, -1.8260586e-06, -2.1429269e-06, -2.0532939e-06, -2.1373399e-06, -2.342127e-06, -2.3871293e-06, -2.5980083e-06, -2.4293864e-06, -2.3568741e-06, -2.0801477e-06, -1.8587702e-06, -1.7074138e-06, -1.5791169e-06, -1.6891695e-06, -1.7635139e-06, -1.9566623e-06, -1.8455385e-06, -2.1080438e-06, -2.0320153e-06, -2.1665641e-06, -2.1571212e-06, -2.3643005e-06, -2.074037e-06, -2.0893195e-06, -1.9232214e-06, -1.7025658e-06, -1.6232691e-06, -1.6510243e-06, -1.7197265e-06, -1.8580166e-06, -1.9258182e-06, -2.0062691e-06, -2.0157544e-06, -2.0394525e-06, -2.0826713e-06, -1.9067459e-06, -2.0218438e-06, -1.9964327e-06, -2.1734356e-06, -2.1242189e-06, -2.4424379e-06, -2.4437198e-06, -2.6022861e-06, -2.4502697e-06, -2.6343237e-06, -2.2225432e-06, -2.3110892e-06, -2.1664638e-06, -2.1287713e-06, -2.011825e-06, -2.2808875e-06, -2.158988e-06, -2.5522458e-06, -2.556647e-06, -2.8299596e-06, -2.9620166e-06, -2.6908558e-06, -3.0163631e-06, -2.6530144e-06, -2.5642676e-06, -2.2324086e-06, -2.0825715e-06, -1.7085644e-06, -1.4025919e-06, -1.4042667e-06, -1.397307e-06, -1.4471031e-06, -1.4352464e-06, -1.6847902e-06, -1.4372545e-06, -1.6405646e-06, -1.5025385e-06, -1.58785e-06, -1.5018164e-06, -1.546755e-06, -1.5307927e-06, -1.5450872e-06, -1.762507e-06, -1.9245396e-06, -2.1342847e-06, -2.083201e-06, -2.1824533e-06, -2.2264199e-06, -1.9521925e-06, -2.1104425e-06, -2.35205e-06, -2.1372429e-06, -2.3874246e-06, -2.3111549e-06, -2.3476044e-06, -1.9828263e-06, -2.1105666e-06, -1.77767e-06, -1.8420129e-06, -1.90373e-06, -1.930438e-06, -2.0727705e-06, -2.1793671e-06, -2.4205829e-06, -2.1275047e-06, -2.4740434e-06, -2.0603233e-06, -2.2409819e-06, -1.7541814e-06, -2.0279909e-06, -1.730486e-06, -1.9476207e-06, -1.7534857e-06, -1.8505329e-06, -2.0095086e-06, -1.618978e-06, -1.8867553e-06, -1.9088163e-06, -1.886491e-06, -1.7468138e-06, -1.8476389e-06, -1.7557932e-06, -1.4058452e-06, -1.6067978e-06, -1.3156005e-06, -1.3659535e-06, -1.0961384e-06, -1.0153987e-06, -9.4432646e-07, -6.6454642e-07, -9.2586387e-07, -1.0025458e-06, -1.0698426e-06, -1.2805659e-06, -1.3957816e-06, -1.504749e-06, -1.3274602e-06, -1.4140738e-06, -1.3504825e-06, -1.3899331e-06, -1.3970904e-06, -1.4744283e-06, -1.4185692e-06, -1.7050143e-06, -1.5382651e-06, -1.5599202e-06, -1.5529446e-06, -1.506719e-06, -1.4330019e-06, -1.240627e-06, -1.2835575e-06, -1.1023492e-06, -1.1632735e-06, -1.1683113e-06, -1.2732747e-06, -1.219676e-06, -1.2890147e-06, -1.1440703e-06, -9.1523203e-07, -8.2035542e-07, -8.7226368e-07, -7.3633722e-07, -9.884313e-07, -8.5961273e-07, -1.2392311e-06, -1.0843573e-06, -1.0707268e-06, -9.571558e-07, -1.0067944e-06, -6.4553431e-07, -4.0506156e-07, -3.3043043e-07, -1.7361598e-07, -1.3118263e-07, -2.9468891e-07, -4.7080768e-07, -6.4225818e-07, -7.5475209e-07, -8.5102358e-07, -6.0803728e-07, -8.1677753e-07, -5.9744241e-07, -7.8274568e-07, -5.3968306e-07, -8.350585e-07, -5.4845851e-07, -5.8427222e-07, -5.1520419e-07, -4.6822083e-07, -6.0910398e-07, -4.4298342e-07, -5.6257054e-07, -2.7562129e-07, -2.5181401e-07, 3.8053095e-08, 2.4159147e-07, 3.6882074e-07, 5.1241897e-07, 4.8644598e-07, 7.2692073e-07, 4.7022181e-07, 7.0384493e-07, 6.8289479e-07, 6.4066943e-07, 8.5657662e-07, 5.8406311e-07, 6.7344028e-07, 4.1435118e-07, 2.7649325e-07, 2.3123522e-07, -1.9399705e-08, 2.6291987e-07, -3.6143527e-08, 4.1732021e-07, 3.3391364e-07, 6.4314122e-07, 7.7139665e-07, 1.1209136e-06, 1.4367421e-06, 1.6319081e-06, 1.7711259e-06, 1.8566403e-06, 1.7371454e-06, 1.4824876e-06, 1.6134811e-06, 1.0707754e-06, 1.3415844e-06, 1.1356512e-06, 1.4106389e-06, 1.4104486e-06, 1.7408528e-06, 2.0744193e-06, 2.079919e-06, 2.1838213e-06, 2.3656145e-06, 2.1909773e-06, 2.3504607e-06, 2.2917643e-06, 2.4505978e-06, 2.0934847e-06, 2.583584e-06, 2.2871518e-06, 2.5116042e-06, 2.6234818e-06, 2.8420594e-06, 3.0011699e-06, 3.3721137e-06, 3.3177881e-06, 3.7014297e-06, 3.4988464e-06, 3.6346743e-06, 3.6031151e-06, 3.6434367e-06, 3.3825082e-06, 3.6445565e-06, 3.2970635e-06, 3.6138927e-06, 3.3753039e-06, 3.7447733e-06, 3.5673385e-06, 3.6078831e-06, 3.5609168e-06, 3.6213054e-06, 3.5038571e-06, 3.7264648e-06, 3.9751613e-06, 3.8206903e-06, 4.1254495e-06, 3.9272576e-06, 4.2386514e-06, 3.815278e-06, 4.2691643e-06, 4.0643683e-06, 4.330484e-06, 4.29042e-06, 4.6035887e-06, 4.4565016e-06, 4.583597e-06, 4.7192276e-06, 4.7442267e-06, 4.734727e-06, 5.0407053e-06, 5.3132589e-06, 5.3419609e-06, 5.7940368e-06, 6.014359e-06, 6.0453411e-06, 6.0996584e-06, 6.064599e-06, 6.1232403e-06, 5.8926808e-06, 6.0748121e-06, 5.9732831e-06, 6.0281785e-06, 5.9558067e-06, 5.8235522e-06, 5.6378228e-06, 5.4438118e-06, 5.3658419e-06, 5.3454619e-06, 5.205238e-06, 5.4038907e-06, 5.0070169e-06, 5.0996156e-06, 4.5688268e-06, 4.5768204e-06, 4.3706204e-06, 4.378131e-06, 4.3035565e-06, 4.4136234e-06, 4.4586055e-06, 4.2999055e-06, 4.2367521e-06, 4.1092479e-06, 3.6691199e-06, 3.7132548e-06, 3.3891334e-06, 3.4132172e-06, 3.3112791e-06, 3.4194779e-06, 3.3548478e-06, 3.4746562e-06, 3.0714297e-06, 3.631046e-06, 2.9155762e-06, 3.3648723e-06, 3.0564361e-06, 3.1977623e-06, 2.9422311e-06, 2.8664619e-06, 2.9553471e-06, 2.6331467e-06, 2.7458985e-06, 2.4857213e-06, 2.5358048e-06, 2.0853043e-06, 2.2717608e-06, 1.7708539e-06, 2.1185441e-06, 1.8057521e-06, 2.1431184e-06, 1.8050008e-06, 2.2162456e-06, 1.8085417e-06, 2.0822527e-06, 1.6735792e-06, 1.9627324e-06, 1.5854033e-06, 1.7829235e-06, 1.7266717e-06, 1.9015957e-06, 2.1904481e-06, 2.0235789e-06, 2.319506e-06, 2.0939101e-06, 1.9725124e-06, 1.8089637e-06, 1.6690528e-06, 1.5539039e-06, 1.5197157e-06, 1.6846562e-06, 1.5117772e-06, 1.6974785e-06, 1.6371901e-06, 1.62875e-06, 1.3414928e-06, 1.5716781e-06, 1.1625945e-06, 1.4214429e-06, 9.0279233e-07, 1.1886867e-06, 1.0201856e-06, 1.1328523e-06, 1.1236831e-06, 1.2940038e-06, 1.5421363e-06, 1.4063536e-06, 1.8374101e-06, 1.4969428e-06, 1.8342753e-06, 1.3619477e-06, 1.6680712e-06, 1.1305091e-06, 1.3914424e-06, 1.1421031e-06, 1.0667439e-06, 9.2969523e-07, 1.0559697e-06, 9.1449135e-07, 1.0647219e-06, 1.0087653e-06, 1.4041236e-06, 1.0653469e-06, 1.5728387e-06, 1.1900372e-06, 1.396327e-06, 9.5831428e-07, 9.8273849e-07, 6.9228567e-07, 8.1312667e-07, 7.1831973e-07, 8.7380434e-07, 1.1589902e-06, 1.1559309e-06, 1.3702947e-06, 1.2662056e-06, 1.5425231e-06, 1.3134162e-06, 1.3669259e-06, 1.3616054e-06, 1.1954299e-06, 1.2969087e-06, 1.2044857e-06, 1.2129433e-06, 1.066829e-06, 1.2888265e-06, 9.1080301e-07, 9.4850302e-07, 5.628118e-07, 7.3976011e-07, 2.4812591e-07, 4.8428843e-07, 2.8183855e-07, 5.7697958e-07, 4.5050618e-07, 8.9398675e-07, 6.1835844e-07, 1.0104357e-06, 8.0297383e-07, 1.048894e-06, 8.5358493e-07, 1.0796489e-06, 8.1287327e-07, 9.8257456e-07, 5.680762e-07, 8.0814245e-07, 5.9584009e-07, 6.3797485e-07, 6.944886e-07, 9.4480563e-07, 9.518683e-07, 1.2123149e-06, 1.5256706e-06, 1.5178348e-06, 1.5515784e-06, 1.7937264e-06, 1.240253e-06, 1.3527793e-06, 1.0316758e-06, 9.3243026e-07, 9.332284e-07, 7.1470557e-07, 8.428729e-07, 6.2857809e-07, 5.4179424e-07, 4.6470621e-07, 3.6276441e-07, 2.814264e-07, 3.295977e-07, 4.0521404e-07, 3.5343026e-07, 3.6958044e-07, 5.0506593e-07, 3.1834025e-07, 3.2582213e-07, 4.3522668e-07, 2.6025184e-07, 3.8900153e-07, 1.0961338e-07, 2.5467694e-07, 1.166893e-07, 5.6772224e-08, 9.1470554e-08, 2.0167496e-07, 3.7911797e-08, 2.6796461e-07, 2.0933361e-07, 2.1677593e-07, 1.5076751e-07, 2.154547e-07, 9.4922825e-08, -1.5619153e-08, 5.6953286e-08, 1.492038e-08, -1.2234541e-07, -7.3945498e-08, -1.4066427e-07, -1.5021338e-07, -8.5765791e-08, -2.5937592e-07, -8.5784093e-08, -3.7865655e-07, -3.3939569e-07, -5.3969692e-07, -6.6329776e-07, -6.7695552e-07, -7.9978318e-07, -6.5715392e-07, -5.8634763e-07, -3.4631253e-07, -2.6236251e-07, -9.1816048e-09, -6.8072671e-08, 4.6884891e-08, -2.1581414e-07, -1.6978596e-07, -3.1446355e-07, -3.5427569e-07, -2.7410849e-07, -2.8441695e-07, -2.4303658e-07, -6.8944944e-08, -1.8188616e-07, 5.0232102e-08, -5.0489499e-08, -3.4827404e-08, -2.0914572e-07, -2.141703e-07]
```

Comment: The integral is a function of `r` or `s`?

Comment: The integral integrates over s

Comment: Is use of a GPU for the integral calculation an option? Presumably you are going to be solving many similar problems - what is going to change, and how much?

Comment: Some thoughts: 1) Each iteration of curve_fit() will call style_exact() 4 times. Once to obtain its value, and 3 times to get the derivative with respect to upsilon, E, and h. Does the integral have an analytic derivative with respect to those variables? If so, there is potentially a 4x speedup. 2) Some profiling shows that integrand() spends 50% of its time computing `j0(s*r)`. If you could avoid that, or cache the results, you could get a significant speed-up. 3) I attempted a re-implementation of the `j0()` function in Numba but was unable to make it faster than SciPy.

Comment: Do you have an example for `points_x` and `points_y`?

Comment: @jared I added an example dataset

Comment: @NickODell I will try caching the j0 function. I will have to check if the integral can be derived for the other variables.

Comment: @MattHaberland This problem implements a model for a so-called wetting ridge according to Style and Dufresne. Its pretty much fixed, maybe I will change which parameters will be fitted. The main thing that will change is the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are certainly some code optimizations in the comments that can speed things up, so I'll complement that by focusing on the integration. If you can use a GPU, you can get two to three orders of magnitude speedup there.

One of the simplest things that you can do to improve the speed without sacrificing too much accuracy is to provide limits of integration that capture the important part of the integral. I plotted the integrand to choose `1e7` as the upper limit, but you can probably develop a heuristic and write something to automatically choose a reasonable value.

```py
args= (x_ax, R, upsilon, E, h)

# infinite upper limit of integration
%timeit -r 1 -n 1 quad_vec(integrand, 0, np.inf, args=args)
# 9.41 s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
res = quad_vec(integrand, 0, np.inf, args=args)

# large, finite upper limit of integration
%timeit quad_vec(integrand, 0, 1e7, args=args)
# 595 ms ± 169 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
res2 = quad_vec(integrand, 0, 1e7 args=args)

# Check error between the two
# (note that `quad_vec` may not be super accurate, anyway;
#  consider checking against `mpmath.quad`)
from scipy import stats
res = quad_vec(integrand, 0, 1e7, args=args)
res0 = quad_vec(integrand, 0, np.inf, args=args)
stats.gmean(abs((res[0] - res0[0])/res0[0]))  # gmean of relative error
# 3.643331971383965e-05
```

You can get much bigger gains without too much trouble by rolling your own integration scheme in CuPy (or find an integration library that makes use of the GPU).

For instance, there is an [implementation](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.12.0/scipy/integrate/_tanhsinh.py) of the [tanh-sinh quadrature rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanh-sinh_quadrature) in SciPy that is relatively simple to adapt to something that uses the GPU, especially if you're willing to go with a fixed step size. tanh-sinh is probably *not* the best rule for this oscillatory integrand; I'm just using it because I'm familiar with it.

```py
import cupy as np  # still np to avoid changing the existing code
from cupyx.scipy.special import j0, j1

# copy-pasted from
# https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.12.0/scipy/integrate/_tanhsinh.py
# then removed comments to reduce length; other optimizations possible
# There are plans to make this Array-API compatible and provide a public 
# interface

_N_BASE_STEPS = 8

def _get_base_step(dtype=np.float64):
    fmin = 4*np.finfo(dtype).tiny
    tmax = np.arcsinh(np.log(2/fmin - 1) / np.pi)
    h0 = tmax / _N_BASE_STEPS
    return h0.astype(dtype)

def _compute_pair(k, h0):
    h = h0 / 2**k
    max = _N_BASE_STEPS * 2**k
    j = np.arange(max+1) if k == 0 else np.arange(1, max+1)
    jh = j * h
    pi_2 = np.pi / 2
    u1 = pi_2*np.cosh(jh)
    u2 = pi_2*np.sinh(jh)
    wj = u1 / np.cosh(u2)**2
    xjc = 1 / (np.exp(u2) * np.cosh(u2))
    wj[0] = wj[0] / 2 if k == 0 else wj[0]
    return xjc, wj

def _transform_to_limits(xjc, wj, a, b):
    alpha = (b - a) / 2
    xj = np.concatenate((-alpha * xjc + b, alpha * xjc + a), axis=-1)
    wj = wj*alpha
    wj = np.concatenate((wj, wj), axis=-1)
    invalid = (xj <= a) | (xj >= b)
    wj[invalid] = 0
    return xj, wj

# simple fixed-step integration function
def integrate(func, a, b, args):
    k = 10  # increase this to improve accuracy 
    step0 = _get_base_step()
    step = step0 / 2**k
    xjc, wj = _compute_pair(k, step0)
    xj, wj = _transform_to_limits(xjc, wj, a, b)
    fj = integrand(xj, *args)
    return fj @ wj * step

# your code
def QSzz_1(s,h,z, upsilon, E):
    # exponential form of the QSzz^-1 function to prevent float overflow,
    # also assumes nu==0.5
    numerator = (1+2*s**2*h**2)*np.exp(-2*s*z) + 0.5*(1+np.exp(-4*s*z))
    denominator = 0.5*(1-np.exp(-4*s*z)) - 2*s*h*np.exp(-2*s*z)
    return (3/(2*s*E)) / (numerator/denominator + (3*upsilon/(2*E))*s)

def integrand(s, r, R, upsilon, E, h):
    return s*(R*j0(s*R) - 2*j1(s*R)/s) * QSzz_1(s, h, h, upsilon, E) * j0(s*r)

h = 0.00005
G = 1000
E = 3*G
R= 0.0002
upsilon = 0.06
gamma = 0.072
x_ax = np.linspace(0, 0.0004, 101, endpoint=True, dtype=np.float64)
r, gamma, R, upsilon, E, h = x_ax, gamma, 0.0002, upsilon, E, h
a = 0
b = 1e7
args = (r[:, np.newaxis], R, upsilon, E, h)

%timeit integrate(integrand, a, b, args)
# 2.14 ms ± 82.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

res = integrate(integrand, a, b, args)

stats.gmean(abs((res - res0[0])/res0[0]))
# 0.00011028421945971745
```

You can trade time for accuracy by increasing `k`. If you don't want to make the upper limit of integration finite, you can also transform the improper integral into one with finite limits of integration with a variable substitution (but you'll need to increase `k` to compensate).

---

Update:
`style_exact`, `fit_func`, and the call to `curve_fit` might look like:

```py
def style_exact(r, gamma, R, upsilon, E, h):
    int_out = integrate(integrand, 0, 1e7, args=(r,R,upsilon,E,h))
    return gamma * int_out

def fit_func(x, upsilon, E,h):
    # Ensure that `r` is a CuPy array align led along new axis; the
    # last axis will be used to evaluate integrand at many abscissae.
    x = cp.asarray(x)[:, np.newaxis]
    res = style_exact(x, gamma, 0.0002, upsilon, E, h)
    return cp.asnumpy(res)

popt_hemi, pcov_hemi = curve_fit(fit_func, points_x, points_y, p0=(upsilon, E, h), bounds=([0,0,0],[np.inf, np.inf, np.inf]))
```

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer, I will test it out and let you know. I only have a Nvidia Quadro P400 in my workstation, which is not very beefy.

Comment: This speeds up the function evaluation by a huge amount! However I am having trouble using this with scipy curve_fit. Both numpy array and cupy array will throw some error. I'll try to copy the function and replace numpy with cupy as you did with the integrate function, but it looks more involved here.

Comment: Have you used `.asnumpy()` on the result array? After that, it will be a regular NumPy array.

Comment: Oh, and if you need NumPy for other things, just `import cupy as cp` and replace `np` with `cp` only in this part of the code. I'll edit that in the answer.

Comment: I amended my answer with the errors. If I understood correctly, then every array that is used in the style function should be a cupy array? I am not doing much else. Converting the result array to numpy also causes a different error.

Comment: Yes, but no array that is seen by `curve_fit` can be a CuPy array. So in the first approach, you can't pass CuPy `points_x` and `points_y` into `curve_fit`. I'll take a look in a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the update, that seems pretty straightforward. Dont know why I didn't figure that one out on my own sorry. I dont have a Cuda GPU at home, I will give your update a try once I get back to work!

Comment: I managed to get it running, thanks. A new problem arises: the cupy fit is much worse than using numpy or the original quad. See the question for a comparison. Do you know why? Can cupy only do float32 maybe?

Comment: Since the numpy version is also pretty fast, this is not really an issue though.

Comment: Check the `dtype` attribute of the resulting array; I think it would be `float64`. To debug, I'd suggest passing the optimal parameters into the CuPy `fit_func`. What is the magnitude of the individual errors? If it's tiny, does changing the guess to `curve_fit` help? Maybe there are slight numerical discrepancies that affects convergence. (The NumPy version is the same code with NumPy arrays and SciPy special functions?)

Comment: Never mind, I had typed an additional zero in the function call. Everything is working perfectly. Thanks again!